# How to process gyroscope values to find orientation using python in real time?

Tags: python, real-time, gyroscope

I need to find in which direction the head is moving in real time using python. The device placed on head returns 9 values (Gyroscope, Acceleration and Magnetometer) in degrees per second unit. Now how do I process these values in real time to get head orientation. I wish to know in which direction the user is moving his/her head like left-right or up-down. How to do it in python?

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript, it should be simple. Just take the start value `zaxis` and calculate decrease or increase degrees of `z` value. So you get the moving direction of your head if your phone is horizontal. Have a look [here](https://www.audero.it/demo/device-orientation-api-demo.html)